# Delete all characters but numbers and -+ in a list, Python 2.7

Tags: python, html, regex, list, beautifulsoup

I have a list like this

```
[u'-107', u'-103', u'-109', u'-101', u'-110', u'-110', u'-110', u'-110', u'-110', u'-110', u'-105', u'-105', u'-105', u'-115', u'-110', u'-110'
```

This list was created from parsing html with BeautifulSoup.  I want to only have the numbers inside the string and the +- sign, for example: -107 for the first list value.  Then I want to create a new list with these values.

Like this:

```
[-107,-103,-109. . . . . . . .]
```

Bonus Question:

Why is the u showing up?

Solved Solution:

The following code is what ended up working for me:

```
odds_matrix_cleaned = [str(x) for x in odds_matrix_dirty]
odds_matrix_cleaned = map(int, odds_matrix_cleaned)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to convert your list of unicode objects into a list of integers?

Comment: `map(int, my_list)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think that is what exactly what I am asking now that I understand what the u means.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
>>> input_list=[u'-107', u'-103', u'-109', u'-101', u'-110', u'-110', u'-110', u'-110', u'-110', u'-110', u'-105', u'-105', u'-105', u'-115', u'-110', u'-110']
>>> output = [int(x) for x in input_list]
>>> print output
[-107, -103, -109, -101, -110, -110, -110, -110, -110, -110, -105, -105, -105, -115, -110, -110]
```

Comment: Gave me the error: TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'generator'

Answer (score 0):

Check below examples :

**Converting unicode string into integer and float**

```
>>> a=u'-100'

>>> int(a)
-100

>>> float(a)
-100.0
```

**Converting string with decimal into integer**

```
>>> a=u'-100.0'

>>> int(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-100.0'
```

**Converting empty string or space into integer**

```
>>> int(u' ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>>>
```

**Converting empty string or space into float**

```
>>> float(u' ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
>>>
```

It seems your value list has some empty strings.
So we need to take care of them.

We can take two approaches here

1. Ignore the empty string

   **OR**
2. Append as it is

Below **code** using second approach

```
a = [u'-107', u'-103', u'-109', u'-101', u'-110', u'-110', u'-110', u'-110', u'-110', u'-110', u'-105', u'-105', u'-105', u'-115', u'-110', u'-110' ,u' ']

converted = []
for i in a:
    try:
        #Check second example. So convert into float
        converted.append(float(i))
    except ValueError:
        pass

print converted
```

**Output**

```
 C:\Users\Dinesh Pundkar\Desktop>python b.py
[-107.0, -103.0, -109.0, -101.0, -110.0, -110.0, -110.0, -110.0, -110.0, -110.0, -105.0, -105.0, -105.0, -115.0, -110.0, -110.0]
```

Comment: This gave me this error.   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: I tried using float() instead and it gave me this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: